# chemical effect

Tags: post-processing, negative-film

I have installation and it is about creating art piece on 16mm film negative.

I'am wondering how can I destroy film negative and what kind of chemical will leave effect on negative or give it vintage, old look?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of effect are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Black and white or color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to destroy it use bleach on the emulsion side of the negative. But there won't be any image, vintage or otherwise, left.